# Leading/prefix 0s in out of for loop

Tags: python, string, for-loop, prefix

I am writing a four loop in my program that writes data to a file. I'm wanting for the output to be formatted as follows

```
frame001 + K.1
frame002 + K.2
...
frame099 + K.99
frame100 + K.100
```

So far I am doing

```
for f in range(1, 100):
    file.write('frame' + str(f) + ' + K.' + str(f) + '\n')
```

I have no problem having the K part come out correctly as K.1-K.100, but I don't know how to have prefix zeros/have it output also frame00F to frameFFF with the appropriate amount of preceding zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> 'frame{0:03d} + K.{0}\n'.format(1)
'frame001 + K.1\n'
>>> 'frame{0:03d} + K.{0}\n'.format(100)
'frame100 + K.100\n'
```

BTW, `range(1, 100)` will not yield `100`. If you want `100` to be included, that should be `range(1, 101)`.

---

If you are using old version of Python (Python 2.5-), use [`%` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) (String formatting operator) instead (need to specify multiple argument unlike `str.format`)

```
>>> 'frame%03d + K.%d\n' % (1, 1)
'frame001 + K.1\n'
>>> 'frame%03d + K.%d\n' % (100, 100)
'frame100 + K.100\n'
```

If you don't want to repeat arguments, you can pass mapping instead with slightly different format specifier:

```
>>> 'frame%(i)03d + K.%(i)d\n' % {'i': 1}
'frame001 + K.1\n'
```

Comment: @user3295674, Maybe you're using old version of Python (2.5-) I will update the answer.

Comment: I imported what I thought was the string library but I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: Thank you, I tried it specifying python 2.6 and it worked - still curious about the same solution for older python versions though :)

Comment: @user3295674, Glad to help you. BTW, I added another detail again.